# How to reference different UIButtons in code

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm building calculator on the iphone for learning purposes.

I have a situation where I have multiple buttons that are Operations(+,-,/) and multiple buttons that are Operands e.g. 1,2,3 etc.

So all the the Operations connect to a operationPressed method in my viewController.

Is there a way in the UI builder to identify each UIButton other than using the Text for the button in the view?

What would be best practice?

---

Update

What about the Identity Label that I can set in the UI builder. can I reference that?

The reason I ask is I want to identify the button but say '/' but the text on the button would be '÷' so that is why i need some other string identifier which ultimately can be pass as an argument to my model.
http://cl.ly/3H1j032f1M1d3A2Y3501

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way this is typically handled is to set each button's `tag` property to some unique integer value, and write action methods that take a `sender` argument, for example:

```
- (void)operationPressed:(id)sender
{
    // cast the argument to a more specific type
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *) sender;

    // get the view's tag
    NSInteger tag = [button tag];

    // Do whatever it was you were going to do...
}
```

**EDIT**

Here's the declaration of the `tag` property from `UIView.h`:

```
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger tag; // default is 0
```

Comment: is it a good idea to use the identity label like so http://cl.ly/3H1j032f1M1d3A2Y3501  Is there a way to reference that in code?

Comment: @DerekOrgan No, the label is simply used to visually identify an object in the Nib File Editor; it's not a property of the object.

Answer (score 1):

You can define tags for your buttons, either in .xib or in code (button.tag = 123)

Define your IBAction with the sender, and check for which button was pressed.

```
- (void) operationPressed: (id) sender
{
    UIButton *op = (UIButton *) sender;

    switch(op.tag)
    {
        case 1: break; // op 1
        case 2: break; // op 2
        ...
    }
}
```

[Edit: Mar 2, 2012] using Storyboard

While in storyboard scene, select the UIButton, then in the right pane, go to button properties, scroll down to see button's view properties, you can set the tag value there.

Comment: Thanks, I don't have a xib file thought. have latest version and using story board. so can i set the tag in the UI builder for the button?

Comment: While in storyboard scene, select the UIButton, then in the right pane, go to button properties, scroll down to see button's view properties, you can set the tag value there.

Answer (score 0):

Before you define tags for each button in Interface Builder, you could also create an outlet for each of them and connect it in Interface Builder

```
- (void)operationPressed:(id)sender
{
    if(self.operationMultiplyButton == sender){

    } else if(…) {

    }

}
```

Personally I try to avoid solutions using tags, as in my opinion they head to redundant information: A pointer is a unique value already, instead it increases the need of documentation.

Comment: A pointer isn't the same value every time you run the app though, so they're in that sense tags are not redundant. The OP plans to have a button for each digit as well as a button for each operand. That's an awful lot of outlets for something this simple.

Comment: In Xcode 4 outlets are easy to make, while going through the inspector in IB for every button isn't less work. The pointer doesn't have to be the same on every run. as the property is connect with the button, it will have the same value during each run.

Comment: Right, but you can't (or at least shouldn't) write a `switch` statement based on pointer values, so it all depends what your code needs to do.

Comment: The funny thing: I had to write a numpad today. A reusable. As you can imaging, my approach is a little bit different. first of all, I use no xib. and to use a switch, I put the buttons in two array. one for the digits, on for the operations. now I get the idea by `idx =[buttons indexOfObject:button]`.

Comment: I often use arrays for similar things myself. And now that iOS has `IBOutletCollection`s, I've gravitated to using those in nib files as an alternative to tagging. Still, tagging has its merits.